# Could not create an object using constructor

Tags: java, constructor, nullpointerexception

There is an interface

```
public interface Rtriangle {
    int getApexX1();
    int getApexY1();
    int getApexX2();
    int getApexY2();
    int getApexX3();
    int getApexY3();
}
```

And a class that implement this interface

```
public class RightTriangle implements Rtriangle{
    private Point a;
    private Point b; 
    private Point c;

    public RightTriangle (int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int x3, int y3){
        this.a.x=x1;
        this.a.y=y1;
        this.b.x=x1;
        this.b.y=y1;
        this.c.x=x1;
        this.c.y=y1;
} 

    public int getApexX1(){
        return a.x;
        }
    public int getApexY1(){
        return a.y;
    }
    public int getApexX2() {
        return b.x;
    }
    public int getApexY2(){
        return b.y;
    }
    public int getApexX3(){
        return c.x;
    }
    public int getApexY3(){
        return c.y;
    }
}
```

Also there is a class that uses this class:

```
public class RtriangleProvider {
    public static Rtriangle getRtriangle(){
        try{
            Rtriangle tr = new RightTriangle(0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0);
            return tr;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.print(e.toString());
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And when I try to use getRtriangle() method I'm getting NullPointerException exception on this line:

```
 Rtriangle tr = new RightTriangle(0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0);
```

on RightTriangle creation.

```
public class TestTriangle {
    @Test
    public void testRight(){
        Rtriangle tr =RtriangleProvider.getRtriangle();
    }
}
```

I can't understand what  is the problem with constructor.I will appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 8):

Look at this part:

```
private Point a;
...

public RightTriangle (int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int x3, int y3){
    this.a.x=x1; 
    ...
}
```

What do you expect the value of `a` to be here? It hasn't been set by anything else, so it will be null. Dereferencing it then causes the exception. I suspect you want:

```
public RightTriangle (int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int x3, int y3){
    a = new Point(x1, y1);
    b = new Point(x2, y2);
    c = new Point(x3, y3);
}
```

Also note that this code uses all 6 parameters, whereas your original code *only* uses `x1` and `y1`.

I'd also encourage you to think more in terms of points - I would rewrite both the interface and constructor to use `Point` values rather than the individual `x` and `y` values.

Answer (score 0):

You never instantiate the `Point`s being used in `RightTriangle`.

You have neither provided what a `Point` actually is, but you surely need to use in `RightTriangle`s constructor at the very start:

```
this.a = new Point();
this.b = new Point();
this.c = new Point();
```

Answer (score 0):

In the lines `this.a.x=x1;` and so forth in your `RightTriangle` constructor, you are accessing your `Point` instance fields' public fields without initializing the `Point` fields themselves first.

Hence the NPE.

Try something along the lines of:

```
this.a = new Point(); // or whatever is the signature of the Point constructor
this.a.x=x1;
// and so forth
```